# Drop down List saves id instead of name in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, cascading

I have cascading 3 dropdown lists. User can select Model Brand and Year and it saves to Boat Model. User has many boats. Boat belongs to User.

The problem is with `#create` action i guess. Because it saves ids instead of the names to Boat Model (Brand Model Year (all string)).

Here is my controller;

```
def new
    @boat = Boat.new
  end

  def create
   @boat = current_user.boats.new(boat_params) if logged_in?
    if @boat.save
      flash[:success] = "Boat created!"
      render 'edit'
    else
      render 'new' 
    end
  end

  def show
  end


  def edit
    @boat = Boat.find(params[:id])
  end


  def update
  end


  def update_years
    # updates year and model based on brand selected
    brand = Brand.find(params[:brand_id])
    # map to name and id for use in our options_for_select
    @years = brand.years.map{|a| [a.name, a.id]}.insert(0, "Select a Year")
    @models   = brand.models.map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}.insert(0, "Select a Model")
  end

  def update_models
    # updates model based on year selected
    year = Year.find(params[:year_id])
    @models = year.models.map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}.insert(0, "Select a Model")
  end
end

private

    def boat_params
      params.require(:boat).permit(:brand, :year, :model)
    end
```

Here is my `#new` view;

```
<% provide(:title, 'List My Boat') %>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@boat) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.label :Brand %>
      <%= f.collection_select(:brand,  Brand.all,  :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Brand"}, {:id => 'brands_select'}) %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.label :Year %>
      <%= f.collection_select(:year, Year.all, :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Year"}, {:id => 'years_select'}) %>
       </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.label :Model %>
      <%= f.collection_select(:model, Model.all, :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Model"}, {:id => 'models_select'}) %>
     </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <%= f.submit "Next", class: "btn btn-primary"%>
     </div>
    <% end %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#brands_select').change(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "<%= update_years_path %>",
        data: {
          brand_id : $('#brands_select').val()
        },
        dataType: "script"
      });
    });
    $('#years_select').change(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "<%= update_models_path %>",
        data: {
          year_id : $('#years_select').val()
        },
        dataType: "script"
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Lastly, if I change the id here

```
<%= f.collection_select(:brand,  Brand.all,  :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Brand"}, {:id => 'brands_select'}) %>
```

to name, then cascading property does not work. So the form does not update itself dynamically.

I have tried something like at `#create` action

```
  year =  Year.find_by("id = ?", params[:year])
  model =  Year.find_by("id = ?", params[:model])
  brand =  Year.find_by("id = ?", params[:brand])
  @boat = current_user.boats.new(:year, year.name, :brand, brand.name, :model, model.name)
```

But then it gives an error because of `@boat = current_user.boats.new(:year, year.name, :brand, brand.name, :model, model.name)` is wrong. I receive

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

error.

EDIT 1:

```
update_models.js.erb
$('#models_select').html("<%= escape_javascript(options_for_select(@models)) %>");

update_years.js.erb
$('#years_select').html("<%= escape_javascript(options_for_select(@years)) %>");
$('#models_select').html("<%= escape_javascript(options_for_select(@models)) %>");
```

Comment: Why would you want the name rather than the id?

Comment: Because 3 drop downs are cascading and they are associated. So when user selects model brand and year, it will take the names and save it to another model associated with user model. Maybe there are different ways of doing it but that is what popped in my mind. I am open to other ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at rails [`collection_select method`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select), ***it's the value method that gets passed on as params, in your case it's the id of year and brand.***

Change your collection select methods to this:

```
<%= f.collection_select(:brand,  Brand.all,  :name, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Brand"}, {:id => 'brands_select'}) %>
<%= f.collection_select(:year, Year.all, :name, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Year"}, {:id => 'years_select'}) %>
```

Your script should be:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#brands_select').change(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "<%= update_years_path %>",
        data: {
          brand_name : $('#brands_select').val()
        },
        dataType: "script"
      });
    });
    $('#years_select').change(function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "<%= update_models_path %>",
        data: {
          year_name : $('#years_select').val()
        },
        dataType: "script"
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

and inside your methods *you need to find brand and year by name instead of ids*

```
def update_years
  # updates year and model based on brand selected
  brand = Brand.find_by_name(params[:brand_name])
  # map to name and id for use in our options_for_select
  @years = brand.years.map{|a| [a.name, a.name]}.insert(0, "Select a Year") #use a.name here instead of a.id
  @models   = brand.models.map{|s| [s.name, s.name]}.insert(0, "Select a Model")#use s.name here instead of s.id
end

def update_models
  # updates model based on year selected
  year = Year.find_by_name(params[:year_name])
  @models = year.models.map{|s| [s.name, s.name]}.insert(0, "Select a Model") #use s.name here instead of s.id
end
```

Comment: But in this case, model does not dynamically update itself. (The last drop down)

Comment: @Shalafister that's a different issue. You need to see how you are updating select when user selects an option.

Comment: Here i get the error: `NoMethodError in BoatsController#update_models

undefined method `models' for nil:NilClass`. I added js file. Thank you

Comment: Here is from network tab, it took 19 as id instead of year name, that is why model (3rd drop down did not update itself). But why it may happen, `https://........................../boats/update_models?year_name=19&_=1429438923235`

Comment: it is strange, i added js files. I am not an js expert but seems nothing wrong to me

Comment: I have checked the database, it actually saves the id of the model and id of the year. It only saves the name of the brand, when i run `<%= f.collection_select(:year, Year.all, :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Year"}, {:id => 'years_select'}) %>
      <%= f.label :Model %>
      <%= f.collection_select(:model, Model.all, :name, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Model"}, {:id => 'models_select'}) %>` and if i change :id to name id does not work

Comment: As you said i think the problem is at the update year part. But I could not find any. Here is the log: `Started GET "/boats/update_models?year_name=23&_=1429271590248" for 88.240.3.128 at 2015-04-17 11:36:39 +0000
Processing by BoatsController#update_models as JS
  Parameters: {"year_name"=>"23", "_"=>"1429271590248"}
  Year Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "years".* FROM "years" WHERE "years"."name" = ? LIMIT 1  [["name", "23"]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `models' for nil:NilClass):
  app/controllers/boats_controller.rb:42:in `update_models'`

Comment: @Shalafister sorry i was up to something. Check updated answer. You need to use name attributes in update_years and update_models method.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked when I put the name attributes!.